# How to add shipping cost in total in order confirmation email in OpenCart 1.5.6.4

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to configure opencart 1.5.6.4 to display shipping cost in the total sum in the order confirmation email sent to the user/client. I'm using the default Cash on Delivery payment with Advanced Shipping PRO module, but not sure if these modules are responsible for the emails sent.

Please, see the attachment - by default it is set to NOT add the shipping cost to the total and it displays it that shipping cost is due on delivery.

[image: opencart order confirmation email doesn't add the shipping cost to total]

Here is how it looks on the Checkout Page:

[image: Shipping cost added to total sum on the Checkout page]

I would like the shipping cost to be added to the total in the order confirmation email.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The email is a confirmation of the order which the customer agreed to.  It will, by default, be the same as the totals shown during confirmation at checkout.  Anything other than this would be at best confusing, at worst bordering on criminal.  If you want to show a shipping charge in the email, it should be included when order is confirmed.

Comment: @billynoah It will make sense only if I'm using some other payment method than CashOnDelivery - client should pay both merchandise and shipping on delivery. It is quite confusing for the costumer: in the checkout page the shipping is calculated in the total, but in the confirmation email the shipping is not included in the total sum.

Comment: oh, maybe i misunderstood.  are you saying it *does* show the shipping total at checkout - just not in the email?  It sounds like you should contact the extension developer for support, as the email should always match the checkout totals.

Comment: @billynoah Please, see the new screenshot I've attached to the post, this is how it looks on the Checkout Page. Is an extension generates the email or Opencart itself? I'm using third party theme (OXY) and third party QuickCheckout module for the checkout page. Is it possible that some of them is creating the email? Thank you

Comment: opencart generates and sends email but there's no telling if one of your mods is affecting the core code.  the totals should be identical - if they are not then it would seem something is wrong.  and btw, i've seend lots of trouble with *certain* quickcheckout extensions.  all this aside, this is not a programming question so not appropriate for stackoverflow.  you should contact extension developer and/or post in the opencart support forums.